# The workbook '*' attempted to access external data using the unsupported provider

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I am trhing to configure  a excel workbook to connect to a cube, I created an analysis data source with the wizard and it works perfectly.

However when I save the xlsx file to a Sharepoint library, and I click on refresh, I get this on the logs:

```
The workbook '*' attempted to access external data using the unsupported provider 'Provider=MSOLAP.6;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2014Multidimensional-EE;Data Source=.;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error'. [Session: 1.V22.15iI7tyox0E34auoMKYnhx14.5.en-US5.en-US36.ea1979ef-25a3-4dfe-a385-e547a4f09a4e1.A1.N User: 0#.w|wingtip\spadmin]
```

I am using pluralsight tutorial for this and followed every step:

```
http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=bill-kulterman&name=configuring-sharepoint-2013-business-intelligence-m4&mode=live&clip=0&course=configuring-sharepoint-2013-business-intelligence
```

Comment: I'm not a Sharepoint expert, but you should verify if the driver is installed on your Sharepoint server, and also verify that you use the proper 32 or 64 bits version depending of the bitness of your Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add: MSOLAP.6

In the trusted provider list. MSOLAP.5 was already there, but excel 2013 uses .6